# How can symmetric encryption be used to create a digital signature? Is it even possible?

Tags: encryption, signature

I want to use symmetric encryption to create a digital signature.

What can be the possible scenarios where symmetric encryption is used to create digital signatures?

Comment: Do you want a digital signature or just message authentication (MAC), in the latter case use CBC-MAC, in the former case, it is not possible!  Note that MAC only fails non-repudation. What is your actual problem?

Comment: Blockciphers can be built into hash functions, which can in turn be built into DSS, if that's what you want. There's also methods to build zero-knowledge proof based on blockcipher, which can also turn into DSS construction.

Comment: If it's desired a MAC rather than digital signature: making CBC-MAC secure requires precautions, like stuffing the message length in the first block. AES-GCM in authentication-only mode might be a practical, easier to implement, and faster option. If it's indeed desired digital signature, and the theoretical outline above is not enough after reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_cryptography#Combining_many_one-time_key_pairs_into_a_hash-based_signature_scheme), please tell the requirements: available symmetric encryption, impossibility to use stateful signature...

Comment: @kelalaka: "MAC only fails non-repudation" sidesteps an essential property of digital signature: no secret is needed on the verifier side, making penetration of a verifier a non-event from the standpoint of the security of others. Independently, non-repudiation is a legal concept, and it's debatable that all digital signature schemes are able to provide it. E.g. in short Schnorr signature, the signer can prepare two messages with different meaning yet the same signature, which makes it incorrect to assume a message is unchanged because it's valid signature is, and facilitates repudiation.

Comment: @fgrieu of course it is. This is why I had asked...